# Use variadic arguments as arguments for sprintf

Tags: perl, variadic-functions

I'd like to program a wrapper around `printf(...)`.

My first attempt was:

```
sub printf2 {
    my $test = sprintf(@_);
    print $test;
}
```

As the array (in scalar context) isn't a format string, this doesn't work (as expected).

Does anyone know a solution? Probably without using any special packages?

**EDIT:** In the real context, I'd like to use `sprintf`. Apparently there is a difference between `printf` and `sprintf`.

Comment: What exactly do you want the wrapper to do?

Comment: The wrapper acts as a logger function which e.g. adds the current time to each output line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this

```
sub pf { printf $_[0],@_[1..$#_] }
```

Comment: This only does the right thing for exactly three arguments. I think you mean `printf $_[0], @_[1 .. $#_]`

Answer (score 8):

The `sprintf` function has a `($@)` [prototype](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#prototype), so the first argument to `sprintf` is always evaluated in scalar context, even if it is an array.

```
$x = sprintf(@a);      # same as  sprintf(scalar @a)
```

So before you call `sprintf`, you need to separate the template from the rest of the arguments.
Here's a concise way:

```
sub printf2 {
    my $test = sprintf(shift, @_);
    print $test;
}
```

Curiously, `printf` doesn't have a prototype and does what you expect.

```
printf(@a);            # same as  printf($a[0], @a[1..$#a])
```

Answer (score 1):

Many of the [named operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc.html) (such as `sprintf`) have special syntaxes. [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html)'s syntax is defined to be

```
sprintf FORMAT, LIST
```

This can often (but not always) be seen using [`prototype`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/prototype.html).

```
>perl -wE"say prototype 'CORE::sprintf'"
$@
```

The problem is that you used one of the following syntaxes instead of the documented syntax.

```
sprintf ARRAY
sprintf LIST
```

Simply switch to the documented syntax to solve your problem.

```
sub printf2 {
   my ( $format, @args ) = @_;
   print sprintf( $format, @args );
}
```

Or if you want to avoid the copying,

```
sub printf2 {
   print sprintf( $_[0], @_[ 1..$#_ ] );
}
```

Same idea with `printf`.

```
sub printf2 {
   printf( $_[0], @_[ 1..$#_ ] );
}
```